# Cross tabulation of two categorical variables

Tags: r, matrix

How can i find the cross tabulation of the following two variables?

```
X Y
6 7 
8 8
9 10
```

I go like this:

```
X <- c(6,8,9)
Y <- c(7,8,10)
X <- factor(X)
Y <- factor(Y)
```

I found the frequencies of `X` and `Y` with the following commands:

```
table(X)
table(Y)
```

but I don't know how to use them.
I tried to print the matrix with the command

```
table(X,Y)
```

but it is not exactly the result I want, which will be like this:

```
  Y 6 7 8 9 10
X
6   0 1 0 0 0
7   0 0 0 0 0 
8   0 0 1 0 0
9   0 0 0 0 1
10  0 0 0 0 0
```

The numbers 6,7,8,9,10 are all the different levels of `X` and `Y`.

Comment: It is unclear what you want; could you please provide an example of what the output should look like for the `X` and `Y` vectors above.  `table(X, Y)` does produce a 3x3 grid though not a `matrix`.  You can make it a `matrix` using `unclass(table(X, Y))`.

Comment: I edited my post above, check it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell `table` that there are levels not included in each variable. (Making `X` and `Y` into factors prematurely actually causes more problems than it's worth.)

```
X <- c(6,8,9)
Y <- c(7,8,10)
vals <- c(X,Y)
levs <- min(vals):max(vals)
table(factor(X,levs),factor(Y,levs))
```

If you start with factors you can use `levs <- sort(union(levels(X),levels(Y)))`.  In this case that would be annoying because R sorts factor levels *alphabetically* ("10" comes before "6").